Formatting bug?
I was looking at this Q&A and I noticed that the OP's signature block on the question looks odd:

It looks like it's trying to write the name twice?
Digging a bit deeper, looks like the user's gravatar doesn't exist. I'm wondering if there's a better way to format it?
